How can I fix the error '.gopclntab pointer size 0 does not match database pointer size 8' when i'm analyzing an Go program
when i'm analyze a Go program with IDA9.0, it didn't rename the function name automatically and when i do 'golang:search_pclntab' under Edit/Other/ it says '.gopclntab pointer size 0 does not match database pointer size 8'.
I have checked the Segments and I found .gopclntab was recognized.
The function names should be renamed.
The Go Version is unknown(with go version command), but it may be built in the docker image of Go-1.20-alpine, so it go version is supported by ida
